# i've got some problems with my spinner

Tags: android, arrays, spinner

So i'm starting a application and the first thing to do is make a description of a city when the city is selected. I can show the description but it make the description of all the cities on the same time and it don't come out when i select another city : it add more and more .

this is my code :

public class Main extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener {

```
TextView description;
Spinner spin;
ArrayAdapter adapter_city;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    description = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.description);

    spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spin);

    adapter_city = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Cities, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter_city.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin.setAdapter(adapter_city);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {


}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
        long id) {
    switch(position){

    case 0 :    description.append(getString(R.string.Paris));

    case 1 :    description.append(getString(R.string.Chicago));

    case 2 :    description.append(getString(R.string.NewYork));
    }




}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
description.append(getString(R.string.Paris));
```

Why don't you just use:

```
description.setText(R.string.Paris);
```

Here is what it should look like:

```
case 0 :    description.setText(R.string.Paris);
            break;

case 1 :    description.setText(R.string.Chicago);
            break;

case 2 :    description.setText(R.string.NewYork);
            break;
```

Comment: i don't know why but when i do that there is this single string for a city in the textView descrption but this is just one and it works with all the item i select . :/

Comment: Ok thank you it was the break which was missing. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `description.setText(CharSequence text)` instead of append.  Append is for appending text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `break`s after every case or execution will continue to all of them when matched:

```
    switch(position){

case 0 :    description.setText(R.string.Paris); break;

case 1 :    description.setText(R.string.Chicago); break;

case 2 :    description.setText(R.string.NewYork); break;
}
```